# Video Upload using python and google-api-python-client

Tags: python, youtube-api

While doing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41752500/api-v3-youtube-upload) I selected the wrong YouTube/Google account to upload the videos to.

When I ran my script for the first time I was presented with a URL like the following to put in the browser to get a "verification code" that allows the script to run. I selected the wrong YouTube / Google account and wish to re-input the code for the other account.

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fyoutube.upload&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&response_type=code&client_id=MY CLIENT ID.apps.googleusercontent.com&access_type=offline
```

However when I now run the script it does not ask for the code only the first time it is run.

How do I get the code changed to the other account?

EDIT:

I couldn't find out after hours of looking so I went another way by deleting YouTube access to the account.  Then gave access to the other account.

Steps I took.

myaccount.google.com/security ---> https

```
Apps connected to your account
Make sure you still use these apps and want to keep them connected.

Google APIs Explorer
MANAGE APPS
```

Clicked on "Manage Apps" and this page came up

myaccount.google.com/permissions ---> https

```
Youtube Upload Script
Has access to YouTube
REMOVE
Youtube Upload Script has access to:    
    YouTube
Manage your YouTube videos
Authorization date: 
6 hours ago
```

I clicked "REMOVE"

I then went back to [cloud google](https://console.cloud.google.com) and re created the access to the other account.

When I ran the script I got the URL again.  I could not add the link as I am not authorised.

After I entered the URL into my browser I was taken to a screen to select which account and grant access. I got the new "Reference Number" to enter into the command line so the script will work.

I successfully uploaded a video to the correct account.