# Add date information to text string in Python Script

Tags: python

I have successfully written a Python script to upload to YouTube with a lot of help.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41773369/video-upload-using-python-and-google-api-python-client) for details if required:

I know need to add date information to the Title as I upload a video every day and they all look very similar on the page.

On my old script that I ran in PHP I could add the date on the end of the description like:

```
$myVideoEntry->setVideoTitle('Parliament Hill Ottawa Canada Time lapse for ' . date('D, jS F Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d")-1)));
```

This would make the Video Title come out like "Parliament Hill Ottawa Canada Time lapse for Fri, 20th January 2017."

The new Python command line looks like the following:

```
python upload_video.py --  file=/home/www/localhost/htdocs/Jpeg2/history2/webcam2-video-hi.avi --title="Parliament Hill Ottawa Canada Timelapse" --description="Video of images taken through the day" --keywords="timelapse, Time-lapse-Photography, Canada, Ontario, video, Hill, weather" --category=19 --privacyStatus="public" --noauth_local_webserver
```

I have tried to add date information but the script has always given errors if the date information was added after the field and not inside the " ".  I am hoping there is a way to do this like in PHP.

My question is how to make the Python Video Title look like the old PHP one with date information.  The date is Yesterdays date as the script runs at midnight so the video if for Yesterday.

Thanks

EDIT:
@ Irisshpunk  I created a test script to see if I can get the date info and they all work except unable to get Yesterdays Date in the format that I want above.:

```
python << END
import time
import datetime
print("Current date and time: " , datetime.datetime.now())
print("Current year: ", datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y"))
print("Month of year: ", datetime.date.today().strftime("%B"))
print("Week number of the year: ", datetime.date.today().strftime("%W"))
print("Weekday of the week: ", datetime.date.today().strftime("%w"))
print("Day of year: ", datetime.date.today().strftime("%j"))
print("Day of the month : ", datetime.date.today().strftime("%d"))
print("Day of week: ", datetime.date.today().strftime("%A"))

import datetime
today = datetime.date.today( )
yesterday = today - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
print yesterday
END
```

This produces the following:

```
('Current date and time: ', datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 21, 18, 42, 18, 750076)) 
('Current year: ', '2017')
('Month of year: ', 'January')
('Week number of the year: ', '03')
('Weekday of the week: ', '6')
('Day of year: ', '021')
('Day of the month : ', '21')
('Day of week: ', 'Saturday')
2017-01-20
```

The following is the script I ran and I do not know how to get the date information added to the "title" string if that's what it is called.

```
echo "Start Youtube upload Python script"
cd /path to/youtube-upload/
python upload_video.py --file=/home/www/localhost/htdocs/Jpeg2/history2/webcam2-video-hi.avi --title="Parliament Hill Ottawa Canada Timelapse" --description="Video of images taken through the day of Parliament House" --keywords="timelapse, Time-lapse-Photography, Parliament, Parliament Hill, Canada, Ontario, video, Hill, weather" --category=19 --privacyStatus="public" --noauth_local_webserver
```

This as is will upload the video without the date. "upload_video.py" is downloaded with the api and is not the problem I din't think.  You can see the code [here](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/python/upload_video.py)

I tried to use the date function like this :

```
python upload_video.py --file=/home/www/localhost/htdocs/Jpeg2/history2/webcam2-video-hi.avi --title="Parliament Hill Ottawa Canada Timelapse"$(date --date="-1 day") --description="Video of images taken through the day of Parliament House" --keywords="timelapse, Time-lapse-Photography, Parliament, Parliament Hill, Canada, Ontario, video, Hill, weather" --category=19 --privacyStatus="public" --noauth_local_webserver
```

And this is the error:

```
Start Youtube upload Python script
usage: upload_video.py [--auth_host_name AUTH_HOST_NAME]
                   [--noauth_local_webserver]
                   [--auth_host_port [AUTH_HOST_PORT [AUTH_HOST_PORT ...]]]
                   [--logging_level {DEBUG,INFO,WARNING,ERROR,CRITICAL}]
                   --file FILE [--title TITLE] [--description DESCRIPTION]
                   [--category CATEGORY] [--keywords KEYWORDS]
                   [--privacyStatus {public,private,unlisted}]
upload_video.py: error: unrecognized arguments: 20 Jan 19:09:39 EST 2017
```

So the question is how to get yesterdays date in Python and add it to this string --title="Parliament Hill Ottawa Canada Timelapse" so it is included in the string.

Comment: Could you share the Python code that you've tried that isn't working? We can't help you fix it if we can't see it. As a hack you could use the unix date utility and add he date on the command line like so: --title="name"$(date --iso-8601)

Comment: always put in question FULL error message (Traceback). We can't read in your mind.

Comment: you have standard module [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html) to work with date and time - you can get `today()` and add some `timedelta()` and convert to string `strftime()` - see [strftime.org](http://strftime.org/) BTW: and use `+` to concatenate strings.

Comment: Irisshpunk - I was able to get some date information in Python but unable to add it to the title without error or it just treated as text.  This is what I have tried in a test script to get date info:

Comment: I added to the question

Comment: You should really post the code where you're attempting to append the date to the title.  However, you can actually solve the problem without using Python (at least on a Linux box) by passing `--title="Parliament Hill Ottawa Canada Timelapse for $(date -v-1d "+%a, %d %B %Y")"` to your script.  This isn't exactly the same (it says 20 instead of 20th), but it's awfully close.

Answer (score 0):

OK I used the info provided to search the date function and have found a solution.  Thank you to all three contributors to the question as I took a bit of each.  You can see the videos [here](https://www.youtube.com/user/dingo001/videos) or [here](http://dingo-den.com) if you are interested.  The first one added with the script will be at midnight Saturday 21 January eastern time.

The final script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
yest=$(date --date="yesterday" +"%A %d %b %Y")
echo "Start Youtube upload Python script"
cd /home/www/localhost/htdocs/scripts/youtube-upload/
python upload_video.py --file=/home/www/localhost/htdocs/Jpeg2/history2/webcam2-video-hi.avi --title="Parliament Hill Ottawa Canada Timelapse for"" $yest" --description="Video of images taken through the day of Parliament House" --keywords="timelapse, Time-lapse-Photography, Parliament, Parliament Hill, Canada, Ontario, video, Hill, weather" --category=19 --privacyStatus="public" --noauth_local_webserver
```